# SharePoint 2010 Content Organizer Rule Unexpected Error

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I just implemented tha content organizer feature in sharepoint, I created a new site content type to use some customized columns in  the Content Organizer Rule, when I upload a document, SharePoint trhow an "unexpected Error", copy the file to the target location and keep one copy at Drop Off Library.

Could some one tell me what I missed, please

Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only.    579f12bf-14fb-4b22-b8ad-ea0fa2cff9d5
08/24/2014 20:04:57.72  w3wp.exe (0x2A10)                           0x4288  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8e2r    Medium      Possible mismatch between the reported error with code = 0x8107210c and message: "Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only." and the returned error with code 0x80070057.

Comment: Please provide us with more details.

Comment: I am using content organizer to move some uploades files. The document is copied in the new location but a copy stills at drop off library and the action returns “UnknownError”.

scanned the log and found the following messages
Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only.
 
Possible mismatch between the reported error with code = 0x8107210c and message: "Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only." and the returned error with code 0x80070057.